# asp.net using c# DropDownList item not selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selected

`ASP.NET` using `C#`:

I've got a `DropdownList` and a `Button`.

In `Page_Load` I fill the `DropdownList` manually via `SQL-Query` with some items from the database.

After click on the button I want to `Alert` the selected item of the list but every time the first item alerts instead of the selected item.

So simple, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: set code to `if(!ispostback){code...} in  page load`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without your code it's hard to say, but I'm guessing on your page load, your reloading your dropdownlist, which is removing the selected item, and giving you the first item every time.

If this is the case, check for the request being a postback, and don't repopulate the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

when click on  button happen postback and run page_load and fill dropdown list agin then show first item that selected.

```
      if (!IsPostBack)
        { 

        //fill the dropdownlist

        }
```